# Programatically set the language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, installation

I'm trying to automate the setup of Drupal multi-site installations as much as possible, we're using each multi-site for a separate country so would like the languages localised for each.

Is there a way to programmatically set the default language? It normally defaults to English. For a Spanish multi-site I would like to set it to Spanish.

The default language seems to be set in SelectLanguageForm.php .Since this happens so early on in the installation process, I can't use `hook_form_alter()` because no modules, profiles, or themes would be loaded at that point.

The default language will be defined basing on the subdomain where Drupal is going to be installed.

Comment: did you tried with module https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_lang ? this is specifically  for the multi sites, but you will also need to install the dependend modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Drush (or Bash running Drush) for that. With `drush site:install` you can set the default language via `--locale`.

The following command will (re)install Drupal using the `expert` install profile and set default language to Ukrainian.

```
drush si expert --locale=uk
```

Source: https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/site/site:install/

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Currently I'm having issues getting Drush running on my Heroku server.

Comment: @NeilNand – If you've started your project with Composer (p.e. https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) then it's as easy as `composer require drush/drush` to include it and then `cd web` and `../vendor/bin/drush si expert --locale=uk`.

Comment: we're using composer and have Drush installed that way, works fine locally, but on Heroku it errors about not being able to fine MySQL which we've not sorted yet. Created a separate question about it on Stack Overflow but with no success as of yet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858830/drush-and-drupal-commands-on-heroku-instances

Answer (score 0):

```
drush config:set system.site default_langcode en
```

Comment: thank you very very much. this has resolved my problem